Using TWE-React with ClojureScript (import() in cljs)
I am currently trying to use TailWindElements-React in Clojure Script.
In JS an example would look like this:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { TECollapse, TERipple } from "tw-elements-react";

export default function App(): JSX.Element {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const toggleShow = () => setShow(!show);

  return (
    <>
      <TERipple rippleColor="light">
        <a
          className="inline-block rounded bg-primary mr-2 px-6 pb-2 pt-2.5 text-xs font-medium uppercase leading-normal text-white shadow-[0_4px_9px_-4px_#3b71ca] transition duration-150 ease-in-out hover:bg-primary-600 hover:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.3),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.2)] focus:bg-primary-600 focus:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.3),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.2)] focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 active:bg-primary-700 active:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.3),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.2)] dark:shadow-[0_4px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.5)] dark:hover:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.2),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.1)] dark:focus:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.2),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.1)] dark:active:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.2),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.1)]"
          role="button"
          onClick={toggleShow}
        >
          Link
        </a>
      </TERipple>
      <TERipple rippleColor="light">
        <button
          type="button"
          className="inline-block rounded bg-primary px-6 pb-2 pt-2.5 text-xs font-medium uppercase leading-normal text-white shadow-[0_4px_9px_-4px_#3b71ca] transition duration-150 ease-in-out hover:bg-primary-600 hover:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.3),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.2)] focus:bg-primary-600 focus:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.3),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.2)] focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 active:bg-primary-700 active:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.3),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.2)] dark:shadow-[0_4px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.5)] dark:hover:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.2),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.1)] dark:focus:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.2),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.1)] dark:active:shadow-[0_8px_9px_-4px_rgba(59,113,202,0.2),0_4px_18px_0_rgba(59,113,202,0.1)]"
          onClick={toggleShow}
        >
          Button
        </button>
      </TERipple>

      <TECollapse show={show}>
        <div className="block rounded-lg bg-white p-6 shadow-lg dark:bg-neutral-700 dark:text-neutral-50">
          Some placeholder content for the collapse component. This panel is
          hidden by default but revealed when the user activates the relevant
          trigger.
        </div>
      </TECollapse>
    </>
  );
}

However, (afaik) TWE uses/requires the import() function. This seems to make problems for CLJS and the workaround is
(ns my.app
  (:require
    [shadow.esm :refer (dynamic-import)]
    [shadow.cljs.modern :refer (js-await)]))

(defn foo []
  (js-await [mod (dynamic-import "https://cdn.pika.dev/preact@^10.0.0")]
    (js/console.log "loaded module" mod)))


as shown here using ES.
So I adapted this to
(ns my.app
  (:require
    [shadow.esm :refer (dynamic-import)]
    [shadow.cljs.modern :refer (js-await)]))

(defn TERipple []
  (js-await [mod (dynamic-import "tw-elements-react")]
    (js/console.log "loaded module" mod)))


However this results in CLJS telling me shadow_esm_import is not defined. I guess I need to change my target in the config to :esm, but then I am unable to mount my app into the DOM.
I am realtively new to CLJS so this is all very confusing. Can someone help me?
Edit: Thomas Heller pointed out, that this is no use of import() but only the basic import syntax. Which would lead to an import via
(:require ["tw-elements-react" :refer (TECollapse TERipple)])

and then using it like
[:> TERipple
...
]

This, however gives me
[:app] Build failure:
Closure compilation failed with 1 errors
--- node_modules/tw-elements-react/dist/js/tw-elements-react.umd.min.js:13
Dynamic import expressions cannot be transpiled.


The JS example is not using import(). It is just a regular import. I know they look similar, but they are entirely different.
There are a lot of common translation examples available in the shadow-cljs docs.
So, import { TECollapse, TERipple } from "tw-elements-react"; translates to
(ns my.app
  (:require ["tw-elements-react" :refer (TECollapse TERipple)]))

Incidentally the tw-elements-react package does indeed use import() internally. This does not change how you :require it from CLJS, but shadow-cljs version 2.26.6+ is required for that to work.

Thank you for the answere. I've alread tried this and got this error
[:app] Build failure: Closure compilation failed with 1 errors node_modules/tw-elements-react/dist/js/tw-elements-react.umd.min.js:13 Dynamic import expressions cannot be transpiled.

Which shadow-cljs version do you use? Support for this was added in 2.26.6, so older versions won't work.

I was indeed running version 2.26.2. I bumped it up and now I now get everything compiled and imported, but if I use [:> TERipple [:div ... ]] the browser throws Minified react error 40: Target container is not a DOM element.

The error seems to stem from an invalid hook call, but I don't know what is wrong with my syntax.

Probably good to ask that as a separate question with the code you tried.

Thank you, I will do that. Maybe you can add the hint with the version to your main answer. Then this post solves all of the problems of my initial post aand I can accept it as an answer.
